# Checked ListBox (WPF)

Tags: wpf, data-binding, checkbox, listbox, c#-3.0

I can't get a checked `ListBox` to work.

My business object (it's a private/nested class, hence the lower-case)

```
    class shop : System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        internal int id;
        string _name;
        internal string name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("name"));
            }
        }

        bool _selected;
        internal bool selected
        {
            get { return _selected; }
            set
            {
                _selected = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("selected"));
            }
        }
    }
```

My XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,0,10,0" Name="lbSelectedShops" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Width="Auto" Content="{Binding Path=name}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=selected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>                                
</ListBox>
```

Databinding in code behind is very simple:

```
lbSelectedShops.ItemsSource = _shops;
```

where `_shops` is an `ObservableCollection<shop>` (containing two elements).

What I get is two **blank** checkboxes in the listbox (no captions, and both ticked off, even though `selected` is set to `true` for all items in the `ItemsSource`).

I'm really frustrated already and I'm sure it must be something very trivial. What is wrong here?

Comment: You can only bind to public properties, so if your class is nested and private I don't think that's going to work. You can look at the Output window in Visual Studio to see where the binding is failing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not working because your properties are internal and for Databinding you need public properties.
From MSDN ([Binding Sources Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643.aspx)):

> You can bind to public properties, sub-properties, as well as
>   indexers, of any common language runtime (CLR) object. The binding
>   engine uses CLR reflection to get the values of the properties.
>   Alternatively, objects that implement ICustomTypeDescriptor or have a
>   registered TypeDescriptionProvider also work with the binding engine.

Comment: That's correct: thanks! (It wouldn't occur to me - after all, the listbox exists in the same app / namespace as the `shop` class).

Answer (score 3):

Binding work only with public properties (and public classes)